# Enumerating multi-core binary partitions

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, partitions

An integer partition $\lambda$ of $n$ is called a *binary partition* provided that its parts are powers of $2$ (dyadic). Example: Let $n=3$. The binary partitions are $\lambda=(2,1)$ and $\lambda=(1,1)$ but not $\lambda=(3)$. If $b(n)$ counts the number of binary partitions of $n$, then
$$\sum_{n\geq0}b(n)x^n=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{1-x^{2^k}}.$$

Given such a partition $\lambda$, let $Y_{\lambda}$ be its corresponding Young diagram. If $\square$ is a cell in $Y_{\lambda}$, construct its hook-lengths $h_{\square}$ in the usual manner. Example: the multi-set of hooks of $\lambda=(2,1)$ is $\{h_{\square}: \square\in Y_{\lambda}\}=\{3,1,1\}$.

A partition $\lambda$ is called an *$(s,t)$-core* if both $s$ and $t$ are absent from the hook-lengths in $Y_{\lambda}$. There has been a flurry of activity regarding this notion.

**Recall 1.** The number of [$(s,s+1)$-core (unrestricted) partitions](http://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan//papers/core.pdf) is the Catalan number $\frac1{s+1}\binom{2s}s$.

**Recall 2.** The number of [$(s,s+1)$-core partitions with distinct parts](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v25i1p57/pdf) is the Fibonacci number $F_{s+1}$.

I like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** What is the total number $f_{s,s+1}$ of $(s,s+1)$-core **binary partitions**?

**Example.** The first few values I can compute: $f_{1,2}=1, f_{2,3}=2, f_{3,4}=4, f_{4,5}=9, f_{5,6}=19$.

Comment: One could also ask for the number of $s$-core binary partitions, since this number is finite.

Comment: If $c_s$ is the number of $s$-core binary partitions, then $c_2=2$, $c_3=9$, $c_4=28$, $c_5=104$ (not in OEIS).

Comment: @RichardStanley: Interesting. Perhaps you can add this to the answer box: why is $c_s$ finite?

Comment: @RichardStanley: I agree with $c_1=1, c_2=2, c_3=9$ but I find $c_4=18$. I did not check $c_5$. I must be missing something with $c_4$.

Comment: You are right, there was a mistake in my code. I now get $c_4=18$ and $c_5=52$. And $c_s$ is finite since any partition with a part repeated $k$ times will have a $k$-hook, and any partition with two consecutive parts differing by at least $k$ will have a $k$-hook.

Comment: I'm trying brute force calculations for binary partitions up to $n=100$ and get slightly different values. For the $f_{s,s+1}$ my sequence $(0, 1, 3, 8, 18, 32, 61, 108, 219)$  can be explained by adding 1 for  the empty partition which I disregard. But for the $c_s$ I get $(0, 2, 8, 18, 52, 92, 160, 264, 659)$ and adding 1 does not help. All values are strictly lower boundaries, but only the last values are probably not reliable. Do you use a more sophisticated enumeration approach ?

Comment: From the comment of  Richard Stanley it follows that the maximal $n$ for the binary partitions to check for calculating $c_s$ is $$n_{max}(s)~=~\left( 2^{\lceil\log_2 s\rceil+1}-1\right)\,(s-1),  $$  which gives the sequence $(0, 3, 14, 21, 60, 75, 90, 105, 248, 279)$. I therefore extended my search up to $n=106$ such that at least $c_7=160$ should be final (up to empty set definition questions).

Comment: Since there are only 8 or 9 partitions counted by $c_3$, could everyone list the partitions explicitly for comparison?

Comment: These are my 9 partitions for $c_3$ including the empty partition:  
{{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {4, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 2, 1, 1}},
and these are the 19 for $c_4$:
{{}, {1}, {2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 
  1}, {4, 1, 1}, {4, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 
  1, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2}, {4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
  1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}

Comment: I have now an improved program that calculates the exact values  by using the structure of the binary partitions. When including the empty partition I get the following exact values for the first 20 $\{k, c_k\}$:   
{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 9}, {4, 19}, {5, 53}, {6, 93}, {7, 161}, {8, 265}, {9, 664}, {10, 1118}, {11, 1638}, {12, 2236}, {13, 3273}, {14, 4763}, {15, 6826}, {16, 9598}, {17, 21828}, {18, 35091}, {19, 49577}, {20, 65496}}

Comment: and for the $\{ s, f_{s,s+1}\}$:
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 9}, {5, 19}, {6, 33}, {7, 62}, {8, 109}, {9, 220}, {10, 362}, {11, 543}, {12, 772}, {13, 1222}, {14, 1864}, {15, 2788}, {16, 4075}, {17, 7832}, {18, 12156}, {19, 17171}, {20, 23017}}

Comment: OEIS:  Sorry, but the terms do not match anything in the table.